# What is an example of a colimit-dense generator which is not dense?

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits

An object $G$ of a category $\mathcal{C}$ is a *dense generator* if every object $X$ is the colimit of the canonical diagram of copies of $G$ mapping to $X$. (This canonical diagram is indexed by the full subcategory of the slice $\mathcal{C}_{/X}$ on the objects of the form $G \to X$.)

An object $G$ is called a *colimit-dense generator* if every object $X$ is a colimit of *some* diagram of copies of $G$. (That means $X$ is the colimit of some functor $F : \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{C}$ with $F(i) = G$ for all objects $i$.)

Is there an example of a colimit-dense generator which is not a dense generator?

Comment: To forestall someone pointing this out, Mike Shulman in http://home.sandiego.edu/~shulman/papers/generators.pdf claims that $\mathbb{Z} \in \text{Ab}$ is colimit-dense but not dense. In fact it is not even colimit-dense! See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/204792/is-every-abelian-group-a-colimit-of-copies-of-z for a discussion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\Bbb R$ is colimit-dense in the category of real vector spaces but not dense
(see 6.F, 6.34 in my book with J. Adámek ["Locally presentable and accessible categories"](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511600579)).

Comment: I like thinking of this in terms of the definition of dense generator which says that $G$ is dense in $C$ if the nerve functor $X \mapsto Hom(i_G-, X)$ is fully faithful (where $i_G: G \to C$ is the inclusion functor). It's easy to see that a natural transformation $Hom(i_{\{\mathbb R\}}, X) \implies Hom(i_{\{\mathbb R\}}, Y)$ consists of a _homogeneous_ function $X \to Y$ but there's no reason for the function to be linear, since the addition map $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is not represented in the category $\{\mathbb R\}$. $\mathbb R^2$ is dense, though, because it does represent this map.

Comment: Thanks, Professor Rosický! This is a very nice example. The canonical colimit of $\mathbb{R}$'s for a vector space $V$ gives you a vector space with basis the projectivization $\mathbb{P}(V)$ (another manifestation of what @Tim says, that $\mathbb{R}$ only imposes the correct restriction on scalar multiplication, not on addition), which is of greater dimension than $V$ for $1< \mathrm{dim}\;V<\infty$.

Comment: It also suggests a generalization: in any [variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)) where every algebra is free and there is at least one nontrivial operation of arity $\geq 2$, the free algebra on one generator fits the bill. These varieties [have been classified](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/157974/varieties-where-every-algebra-is-free): they are either modules over a division ring or affine spaces over a division ring.

Comment: Excellent, now I can finally fix the note of mine that Qiaochu mentioned in a comment by including a correct example.  This also suggests that perhaps my incorrect example was supposed to be $\mathbb{Z}$ in the category of _free_ abelian groups.

Comment: In free abelian groups the $\mathbb{Z}$ example does seem to work, @MikeShulman. By the way, thanks a lot for writing that note and several other extremely useful things that you've written that aren't meant to be published (I would guess), such as blog posts.